# Django insert: what does this error mean

Tags: django, save

can you please tell me, what does this error means :

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

traceback says:

> Exception Type: TypeError at /banque Exception Value: int() argument
>   must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
>   'DeferredAttribute'

I guess this error is a saving error :
**here is my view :** :

```
class BanqueViews(FormView):

def get(self, request,*args,**kwargs):
    #form=SubmitUrlForm()
    if request.user.is_active :
        current_user = request.user
        #form=FormBanque()
        form1=banqueInfo()
        form2=AjoutBanque()
        formset = BanqueFormSet()
        context={"formset":formset,"current_user":current_user,"form2":form2,"form1":form1}
        return render(request,"appOne/banquemineFormsPy.html", context)

def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    current_user = request.user.id
    if request.method == "POST":
        p=int(request.POST['numpiece'])
        print(p)
        formset = BanqueFormSet(request.POST)
        form1=banqueInfo(request.POST,request.FILES);
        nom=request.POST['banque_name']
        rib=request.POST['banque_rib']
        if form1.is_valid():
            tmp=banque.objects.get(nom=nom,rib=rib)# bank name+rib should be unique
            print(tmp)
            bq=releve_bancaire(id_banque_id=tmp.id) # 
            bq.save()
            for f in formset:
                if f.is_valid():
                    cln=f.cleaned_data
                    id_fac=facture
                    tier="";
                    montantcred=f.cleaned_data.get('montantcred')
                    montantdeb=f.cleaned_data.get('montantdeb')
                    typeTiers=f.cleaned_data.get('typeTiers')
                    if typeTiers=="Client":
                        id_tier=client.objects.get(nom=cln.get('tiers'))
                        tier=id_tier.nom
                        id_fac=facture.objects.get(numfac=cln.get('numfacture').numfac,id_client_id=id_tier.id,type_fact="vente")
                    elif typeTiers=="Fournisseur":
                        id_tier=fournisseur.objects.get(nom=cln.get('tiers'))
                        #print(id_tier.id)
                        tier=id_tier.nom
                        id_fac=facture.objects.get(numfac=cln.get('numfacture').numfac,id_fournisseur_id=id_tier.id,type_fact="achat")
                    else:
                        tier=cln.get('tiers')
                        print(tier)

                    if montantdeb!=None and montantcred==None :
                        print("debitnot null")
                        s=False 
                    elif montantcred!=None and montantdeb==None :
                        print("credit not null")
                        s=True
                    b=operation_Bancaire(id_releve=bq,id_facture=id_fac.id,montantdeb=f.cleaned_data.get('montantdeb'),montantcred=f.cleaned_data.get('montantcred'),sens_operation=s,type_tiers=f.cleaned_data.get('typeTiers'),tiers=tier,date_operation=f.cleaned_data.get('dateOperation'),designation=f.cleaned_data.get("designation"))
                    b.save()
                    print('type de facture')
                    print(type(id_fac.type_fact))

                else: 
                    print("nooooott")
        else :
            print("form1 not valid")
    else:
        formset = forms.BanqueFormSet(request.POST or None) 

    context={"formset":formset,"form1":form1}
    return render(request,"appOne/banquemineFormsPy.html",context)
```

from what I see The `tier` variable is the problem. but dont know what is the exact problem.

Comment: Can you add your view?

Comment: of course I will do so

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I've added my view

Answer (score 0):

I realised what is the problem. `id_fac` can be a null  `facture` object, if the if conditions dont exist, so it wont be inserted on `id_facture` field.